# 3D Conv on non-overlapping blocks of a 3D tensor then remapping them (pytorch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

Hi I have a 3D tensor of size (128,128,128) as input to my model. When it enters the model it has the shape (8, 4, 128, 128, 128) which is (Batch, Channels, H, W, D).

I would like to separate the channels and perform a convolution on blocks of (32,32,32) for this (128,128,128) input. Then I wish to take the conv weights and multiply it with the input values to the conv and remap them to a (128,128,128) block.

My current inefficient solution (using many for loops, converting between numpy<->tensor, and scikit-image) is below however it takes too long and requires too much memory. What's the best way to do this on tensors?

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks

class LFBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(128,128,128), kernel_size=(1,1,1), blk_div=4):
        super(LFBlock,self).__init__()      

        # Divides the (128,128,128)//4 -> (32,32,32)
        self.block_shape = (input_shape[0]//blk_div, input_shape[1]//blk_div, input_shape[2]//blk_div)

        self.num_blocks = (input_shape[0]//self.block_shape[0])*(input_shape[0]//self.block_shape[0])*\
        (input_shape[0]//self.block_shape[0])

        conv_list = []
        for n in range(self.num_blocks):
            conv_list.append(nn.Conv3d(1,1, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True))

        self.conv1x1s = nn.ModuleList(conv_list)        

    def forward(self, lf_in):
        # Batch
        for i in range(lf_in.shape[0]):
            # Modality
            for ch in range(lf_in.shape[1]):
                x_lf = lf_in[i,ch,:]
                lf_blocks = view_as_blocks(x_lf.cpu().numpy(), block_shape=self.block_shape)

                # Do Conv3d on each block 
                for x in range(len(lf_blocks)):
                    for y in range(len(lf_blocks)):
                        for z in range(len(lf_blocks)):

                            conv_idx = x*len(lf_blocks) + y*len(lf_blocks) + z

                            # Convolve the block, then multiply with the weight of the block. 
                            tensor_img = torch.from_numpy(lf_blocks[x,y,z])[None, None,:]
                            conv = self.conv1x1s[conv_idx](tensor_img.cuda())

                            # w * x. 
                            # view_as_blocks returns a view so modifications are done in-place

                            lf_blocks[x,y,z] = tensor_img.cpu()*self.conv1x1s[conv_idx].weight.data.cpu()

        # Linearly sum the modalities together
        # out = w0*x0 + w1*x1 + w2*x2 + w3*x3 
        out = (lf_in[:,0]+lf_in[:,1]+lf_in[:,2]+lf_in[:,3])[:,None]

        return out
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!